# Как создать выпадающий список из enum'а в ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

> Внимание! Это перевод вопроса [How do you create a dropdownlist from
>   an enum in ASP.NET
>   MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388483/how-do-you-create-a-dropdownlist-from-an-enum-in-asp-net-mvc)

Я хочу создать выпадающий список `Html.DropDownList` на основе моего перечисления:

```
public enum ItemTypes
{
    Movie = 1,
    Game = 2,
    Book = 3
}
```

Как мне это реализовать?

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388483/

Answer (score 2):

### В MVC v5.1 используйте Html.EnumDropDownListFor

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(
    x => x.YourEnumField,
    "Select My Type", 
    new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Также в этой версии поддерживается атрибут `Display`: вы можете добавить к каждому значению перечисления атрибуты вида `[Display(Name = "Sample")]` и тот же самый код будет выводить в выпадающий список ваши сообщения.

### Для MVC v5 используйте EnumHelper

```
@Html.DropDownList("MyType", 
   EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(MyType)) , 
   "Select My Type", 
   new { @class = "form-control" })
```

### Для MVC 5 и ниже

Используйте следующий extention:

```
namespace MyApp.Common
{
    public static class MyExtensions{
        public static SelectList ToSelectList<TEnum>(this TEnum enumObj)
            where TEnum : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
        {
            var values = from TEnum e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum))
                select new { Id = e, Name = e.ToString() };
            return new SelectList(values, "Id", "Name", enumObj);
        }
    }
}
```

Это позволит вам писать так:

```
ViewData["taskStatus"] = task.Status.ToSelectList();
```

Comment: Это прекрасно, но в случае любого другого языка (не английского) встает проблема - прямой перенос значений из Enum не годится, нужен перевод. Как быть? Добавите пример для русского языка?